# What is the difference between ":" and "::" when using before and after?

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering if I should use ":" or "::" when using :(:)before and :(:)after. I am wondering if there is a difference.

Comment: Did you see any difference when you changed from 1 to the other?

Comment: Did you search for this? I imagine this would be extremely easy to find information on.

Comment: `::before` is correct, `:before` exists for backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ::before notation (with two colons) was introduced in CSS3 in
>   order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and
>   pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced
>   in CSS 2.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

As before is a pseudo ELEMENT and not a pseudo CLASS (like :hover) two colons is better (thus following the CSS3 standard).